# Database Triggers, is it Async?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asynchronous, triggers

I am planning to audit/log few events on my Web site (like adding/updating/deleting few tables). I am planning to add database triggers, I think over the time the audit table may have lot of data and inserting row in that table may take more time.
My question is that the triggers will run Asynchronous or whether it needs to completed before the front end call returns?

Thanks

Comment: _Almost_ a dupe but not quite. The other Q was asking how to make a trigger async, this one's asking whether a trigger is sync or async. While the _answers_ will have a lot of crossover, I never consider a question a dupe unless it's a proper subset of another (ie, the _question_ has to be the same). Just my $.02.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly they would be synchronous since, otherwise, you've blown the whole point of atomicity away (a change may be made to a table atomically then the trigger may fail, meaning that your audit trail is useless).

I'm not saying async triggers aren't possible but I can't see them being of any use to you.

If you're worried about the table getting large, there are other ways to handle that. One is partitioning (based on date for example) or, if that's not available, periodic transfer of audit rows to date-based archive tables, followed by their deletion in the main table.

That way, the main table only ever holds data for the last `N` months and all other data is stored elsewhere.

Comment: The most simple way is just to turn on audit features in sql server.

Comment: @TomTom: as far as I know, this is crude (no filtering, logs system stuff and replication etc) compared to CDC or using triggers

Comment: It also is integrated, takes less effort to develop and has a certain level of testing already applied.

Answer (score 2):

Triggers are *always* synchronous. They run as part of the transaction whether explicit (with `BEGIN TRAN`) or implied (with INSERT etc).

In most applications, logging and auditing is mandatory: if the write to a log or history table fails in a trigger, then then parent INSERT etc fails too.

Triggers only a take a long time when coded badly with loops, or sending emails, or invoking the [MS Word Spell Checker](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Miscellaneous/callingcomfromtsql/2085/) or [calling web services](http://clicpharmacodebits.wordpress.com/2010/11/27/call-a-web-service-from-sql-server-trigger/)

Instead of triggers you can also use [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627397.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

- I'd suggest to create an appropriate audit-table(s) structure
- Example:- A primate audit table and a secondary table with old & new values
- Audit-logs could be managed via triggers
- It shouldn't be an overhead if managed appropriately
- You should have archival process in place